# Inserting image array into complex structure using HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array image: `lstImageSlider`.

I need a loop to `foreach` that array and insert it into the HTML page.

The HTML code from a theme has structure that is difficult to insert.

This is because it has `slider__item--0` - `1` - `2` - `3`. Loop this.

I can set this code to `foreach $lstImageSlider as $item`.

```````````````````````
``````````````````````
`    thumbnail       `
``````````````````````
`  image 1 ` image 2 `   
``````````````````````
```````````````````````

HTML code:

```
<div class="property__ribon">transaction-related</div>
    <div id="properties-thumbs" class="slider slider--small js-slider-thumbs">
        <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
        <div class="slider__item--0"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='0'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>Awesome Kitchen!!!</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--1"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='1'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>2</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--2"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='2'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>3</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--3"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='3'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>Ok</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--0"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='4'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>5</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--1"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='5'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>6</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--2"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='6'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>7</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--3"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='7'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>8</span></a></div>
        <div class="slider__item--0"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='8'><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>The end</span></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slider--thumbs">
        <div class="slider__wrap">
            <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
                <div data-slide-rel='0' class="slider__item--0">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='1' class="slider__item--1">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='2' class="slider__item--2">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='3' class="slider__item--3">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='4' class="slider__item--0">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='5' class="slider__item--1">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='6' class="slider__item--2">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='7' class="slider__item--3">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div data-slide-rel='8' class="slider__item--0">
                <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a `counter` in your loop and set it to zero if it is greater than 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure which you want , but hope it will help you, create counter and if counter >= 3 then set 0

```
<div class="property__ribon">transaction-related</div>
<div id="properties-thumbs" class="slider slider--small js-slider-thumbs">
    <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
        <?php
        $first_counter = 0;
        foreach ($lstImageSlider as $item) {

            ?>
            <div class="slider__item--<?=$first_counter?>"><a href="src/image.jpg" data-gallery-index='<?=$first_counter?>'><img
                        src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""><span>Awesome Kitchen!!!</span></a></div>
            <?php
            $first_counter++;
            if ($first_counter >= 3) {
                $first_counter = 0;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider--thumbs">
    <div class="slider__wrap">
        <div class="slider__block js-slick-slider">
            <?php
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($lstImageSlider as $item) {

                ?>
                <div data-slide-rel='<?= $counter ?>' class="slider__item--<?= $counter ?>">
                    <div class="slider__img"><img src="assets/img/lazy-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $counter++;
                if ($counter >= 3) {
                    $counter = 0;
                }
            }
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope it will help you, any confusion then inform me

Comment: Seem you lost class: `<div id="properties-thumbs" class="slider slider--small js-slider-thumbs">`?

Comment: check my update answer which complete code, it is not optimized code but it will complete your porblem

Comment: Can you have the best way to do this? See your code is not inheritance.

Comment: in this case you can use this code and if you change this then need more code update so this is ok

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're doing with the items, I assume you're updating the document with js?  Or you could output your lines of HTML within this loop. Anyway, this is how you can loop over your items and get the correct classname at the same time:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($lstImageSlider); $i++){
  $j = $i % 3;
  $item = $lstImageSlider[$i];
  $classname = "slider__item--".$j;
}
```